# Lazy load dynamic images php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, lazy-loading

I have a search page with sometimes more than 50 results. Each result has a slider with images that are dynamic. Now I want to lazy load the extra images so only the first image is loaded and the other images are loaded when needed or after page load

My code is the following

```
<div class="my-slider">
<ul>
<li>
<div class="listimagecontainer">
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/for-sale/<?php echo $permalink; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $listing_photo; ?>" ('thumb') alt="Photo of <?php echo $listing_ref; ?>" height="200px" ;/> 
</a>
</div>
</li> <!-- // The following needs lazy loading  -->
     <?php  
     if (is_array($extraimages)){
     $i = 1;
     foreach ( $extraimages as $extraimage ) {
     if ($i++ == 5) break;
     ?>
     <li>
     <div class="listimagecontainer">
     <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/for-sale/<?php echo $permalink; ?>">
     <img src="<?php echo pods_image_url( $extraimage, 'thumb' ); ?>" alt="Photo of <?php echo $listing_ref; ?>"  height="200px"> 
     </a>
     </div>
     </li>
     <?php } //end foreach ?>
     <?php } //end if ?>
</ul> 
</div> <!-- // end div.my-slider -->
```

Comment: Use data-src for image paths and change it to src when needed.

Comment: What's your question?